# middle of linked list

Tags: c++

how to find the middle of the linked list when we are not informed of its size and it must be performed using only one loop and only one pointer.

Comment: Is that the whole question? Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: Is this a singly-linked or doubly-linked list?

Comment: how to find the answer to my homework question using only one internet connection and only one stackoverflow website...

Comment: Sounds like a trick question.  In order to identify the middle of the list, you need to know its length.  In order to know its length, you need to loop to the end of the list.

Comment: @Parappa: Wrang-wrang's answer shows that you can calculate the middle at the same time you calculate the length.

Comment: Are you allowed to destroy the list in the process?

Comment: Uhm, there's no "middle node" if the list has an even number of nodes...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about

```
LinkedList * llist = getLList(); // the linked list
Node * node = llist.head;

while ( node ) {
    node = node.next;
    if ( node ) {
        node  = node.next;
        llist.remove( llist.head );
    }
}
// now llist.head is (er, um... was) the middle node.  
// hope you didn't need the rest of the list.
```

Comment: But you are using two pointers. Definitely "e" and definitely "head". wrang-wrang's solution seems to me just the same...

I think there is no answer to this question. You just can't handle the L1 list with one pointer (because when you move it, you loose your head (well... list head))

Comment: @SadSido:  Obviously, if I have a linked list, I have a bunch of pointers, including the head.  I assumed that the question meant one pointer, in addition to those already in the the list.

Comment: @SadSido: Yes, I do realize that I am destroying the list in the process.  However, since the requirements were so unnatural, I didn't think the solution needed to be extra-resilient.

Answer (score 8):

```
Node *m,*e,*head; /* head is given */
m=e=head;
while(e) {
  e=e->next;
  if (e) {
    e=e->next;
    m=m->next;
  }
}
/* now m is the middle node */
```

Sorry, I had to use 2 pointers :)

---

Adding this to your answer, because a minor tweak reduces the number of pointers to 1. I hope you don't mind:

```
Node m,*e,*head; /* head is given */
e = head;
if (e) m = *e;
while(e) {
  e = e->next;
  if (e) {
    e = e->next;
    m = *(m.next);
  }
}
/* now m is the middle node */
```

Comment: Well, it's not challenging at all when you cheat.

Comment: @rlbond: It is still very clever, though.

Comment: @rlbond: if you think of a better solution, propose it instead of grumbling, it seems to me the most logical solution. Though obviously the middle node in case of an even number of nodes is quite debatable.

Comment: @Matthieu, but the problem was explicitly posed as requiring that it "must be performed using only one loop and only one pointer." It's nice and clean, but not a solution for the problem as posed in the question.

Comment: I'm happy to have Mike's code stay, but I have to point out that the Node m contains a pointer (m.next), so it's a technicality :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's sort of a hack, since it's functionally equivalent to 2 loops. But still, it is only 1 loop.

```
Node* middle(Node* const begin)
{
    Node* current = begin;
    bool size_known = false;
    int size = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!size_known)
        {
            if (current)
            {
                ++size;
                current = current->next;
            }
            else
            {
                current = begin;
                size_known = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (size <= 1)
                return current;
            current = current->next;
            size -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is using an extra bool and an extra int different from using an extra pointer?

Answer (score 1):

see my code. it works on my FC9 x86_64 correctly, the function "middle()" is that what you want:

```
static struct node *middle(struct node *head)
{
        struct node *mid = head;
        int flag = 0;
        while (NULL != head) {
                head = head->next;
                flag = !flag;
                if (flag) {
                        mid = mid->next;
                }
        }
        return mid;
}
```

EDIT: remove code except the middle().

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same as wrang-wrang's solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use skip list in this case:

1) While traversing each node in the Linked List make a skip list of the odd numbered nodes. Time: O(n) Space: O(n/2)

2) Now when you reach the end of the list divide the legnth by 2 and add 1 to get the middle element index.

3) Search for the index in the skip list O(logn) time.

So, Overall Time Complexity of the algorithm would be :

**O(n)(1 traversal) + O(logn)(Searching Skip list) = O(n)
Space Complexity : O(n/2)**

Please reply if this is inefficient....

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your list using the provided head pointer and increment your one allowed pointer (I assume from your ambiguously-worded question that you're allowed one pointer *besides* the one that was passed in) once for every two increments of the head pointer.

```
Node* middle( Node* head )
{
    Node* middle = head;
    while (head != NULL) {
        head = head->next;

        if (head->next != NULL) {
            head = head->next;
            middle = middle->next;
        }
    }
    return middle;
}
```

There are edge cases ignored here (like what's the middle of a list with an even number of elements).

Answer (score -1):

The C++ way to find the middle of the list since you have tagged c++:

```
#include <list> 
using namespace std;

using IntegerList = list<int>; 

int main() { 
     IntegerList l; 
     for (int i : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
          l.push_back(i * 1); 

     auto m = l.begin(); 
     bool even = false; 
     for(auto &z:l) { 
         if (even) ++m; 
         even = !even; 
     }

     cout << "\nmiddle of the list:" << *m << "\n";
}
```